# Integrals: How to find the correct integral to compare with?

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $$\int_1^\infty \frac{e^{-1/x}-1}{x^{2/3}}$$

Now, the limit $$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\frac{e^{-1/x}-1}{x^{2/3}}}{x^{-5/3}} = -1$$

And since $\int_1^\infty x^{-5/3} < \infty$ our integral converges too.

My question is: What is the intention behind that? How can one identify the right integral to compare with?

Comment: I think you mean $\int_0^\infty x^{-5/3}\,dx<\infty$.

Comment: which is false : $\int_a^\infty x^{-5/3} dx < \infty$ for any $a > 0$ but $\int_0^a x^{-5/3} dx$ diverges

Comment: edited question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By intention, do you perhaps mean intuition? In this case, a series expansion of $e^{1/x}$ for large $x$ (i.e an expansion of $e^t$ for small $t$) will give it to you:

We have, as $t\to 0$,
$$
e^t=1+t+O(t^2)
$$
and hence
$$
e^{-1/x}=1-\frac{1}{x}+O(1/x^2)
$$
as $x\to +\infty$. Inserting this, we find that
$$
\frac{e^{-1/x}-1}{x^{2/3}}=-\frac{1}{x^{5/3}}+O(1/x^{8/3}).
$$
From this it is clear that one could compare with $1/x^{5/3}$.